# MaxLength property - change default color

Tags: flutter, properties, maxlength

i like to change the default color of the **maxLength** property to the same color as **TextFormField**. Does anyone got a solution for the problem?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following example should help, just change the `color` property to the one you desire:

```
TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(
                          counterStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
                    ...
                    ...
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply this to all TextFields, you can apply `InputDecoration` to the theme, e.g. the dark theme:

```dart
MaterialApp(
    ...,
    darkTheme: ThemeData(
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
              counterStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ...
    )
)
```